# Accessing previous and next element from String array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

For the given input `"<Hello>/What <I am>/Who <fine>/SKIP"` stored in a string array in Java such as:

```
String arr[] = {"<","Hello",">","/What","<","I","am",">","/Who","<","fine",">","/SKIP"};
```

How do I get the output in the format given below:

Expected output:

```
Hello \tab What\newline   
I     \tab -\newline   
am    \tab Who\newline   
fine  \tab SKIP\newline
```

My code is:

```
public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String arr[] = {"<","Hello",">","/What","<","I","am",">","/Who","<","fine",">","/SKIP"};
        String current=null;
        String next =null;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

            current = arr[i];
            next = arr[i+1];
            if(current.equals("<")){

            }
            else if (!(current.equals(">"))&& !(next.equals("/Who"))|!(next.equals("/What"))
                    |!(next.equals("Who"))|!(next.equals("/SKIP"))){

                System.out.println(current+"\t"+"-");
            }
            else if ((current.equals(">"))&& (next.equals("/Who"))){

                System.out.println(current+"\t"+"-");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(arr[i]+"\t"+"-");
            }
            //System.out.println(arr[i+4]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the current output?

Comment: Couple of things: 1. When you're at the end of your loop and on the last element, You don't have a "next" so you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. for "next = arr[i+1];" 2. Why not sift through your array and put them into a list? That way you can skip the "<" and ">" strings; therefore, not worry about them during processing.

Comment: Also, "/Who" comes before "fine" in your input, BUT displays after "fine" in your desired output.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake.I have changed the desired output. Will ArrayList and ListIterator solve the problem?